# how to rebind array to dataTables.net grid

Tags: jquery

I am using dataTables.net jquery grid to display data in html table. I couldn't find a method to set the array as datasource dynamically and rebind the grid.

Please let me know.

Comment: can you please add code snippets on how you wanted it. I can help you better with that.

Comment: THis is how I am doing now. But I am looking for something like
oTable.fnRebind(array);

function RebindGrid(empno) {
    oTable.fnClearTable();    
    //get the employee map records.
    var empmaprecords = getEmpTotalsMap(empno);
    if (empmaprecords !== null) {
        for (i in empmaprecords) {
            recordIndex = empmaprecords[i].index;
            //add the records to the datatable.
            oTable.fnAddData([emptotals[recordIndex][0], emptotals[recordIndex][2].toFixed(2), emptotals[recordIndex][1]]);            
        }      
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can update the datatable by calling `fnDraw()` method. However the Datatables will read the data again from the actual data source (Ajax URI, in your case) **ONLY** if **`bServerSide: true`** is set (by which you are telling the Datatables that all the processing is done at server side).

One side effect of `bServerSide: true` is that you need send the pagination details (iTotalRecords & iTotalDisplayRecords, .. ) & other data in the Ajax response (see [Server-side Processing](http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side) docs).

Othre side effect is that filtering will not work any longer :( Datatable can't filter the partial data which it has.